# How to set dynamic content property via class name matching?

Tags: css

I'm currently using CSS to print short alphanumeric codes into an icon, using only a class name.

I have over 100 lines in an auto-generated CSS file that looks like this:

```
.icon-aa:before{ content:"AA"; }
.icon-ab:before{ content:"AB"; }
 /* .. and so on .. */
```

It's clunky, but manageable .. until now.

I now need to add hundreds more codes and I must find a better way of doing this dynamically.

Is there any way to match the suffix of the CSS class and dynamically insert it into the content property?

I don't have access to any other HTML attributes other than the class name.

Comment: Not with raw CSS. A pre-processor like SASS or LESS might help you though.

Comment: I'm open to Sass solutions, although I'd still prefer to avoid thousands of lines of CSS which I assume Sass would generate.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible if you do it a bit differently.

Instead of appending the 2-letter content to the end of the class name, create 1 class, and then add the 2-letter content to another attribute, like so:

```
<div class="icon" content="AA"></div>
<div class="icon" content="AB"></div>
```

Then in your CSS, use attr() to retrieve the `content` attribute.

```
.icon:before
{
    content: attr(content);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mwt9me0/)

---

If you can't add any other attributes, I'd advise you to use a child element, like this:

```
<div class="icon">
    <div class="content">AA</div>
</div>
<div class="icon">
    <div class="content">AB</div>
</div>
```

Then just use whatever CSS you were using for your `:before` to position the new child `<div>` in the same place:

```
.icon .content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -10px;

    z-index: 1;
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to any other HTML attributes other than the class name.

Comment: That makes it a bit more difficult. I would advise you still use one class and use a child element (like a div or a span) with similar styling to your `:before` pseudo-element's styling.

Comment: I don't have access to the HTML like this either. However, I could use JavaScript to match the class names and set content attributes like in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first, you can use `attr` as a content function, but if you do not have access to any other HTML attributes, you'll have to change the main CSS selector. Something like this:

```
div#container p:before{ content:attr(class); }
```

Comment: I'm assuming this will print "icon-aa" instead of "aa" though, right?

Comment: It will print "icon-aa"; Right.